# How to control fan speeds on ASUS laptop (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Tags: asus, fan

Just as the question asks, I want to know how to control fan speeds. Because whenever I run any CPU / GPU intensive application, the fans just don't kick in. They are always too quiet and this causes bad peformance in games. My laptop model is ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DY-BQ024T, OS version is 20.04.1 LTS. On Windows however, there is an application which allows fan speed controlling as well as a hotkey (Fn + F5). The hotkey does nothing in Ubuntu.

Comment: You can try running `sensors-detect` and look for anything detected in the SuperIO section.  That would allow you to control the fans using the pwm interface.  Otherwise you'd have to look for an ACPI based solution since this is a laptop,

Comment: Okay so I have no idea what I did, but somehow the fans magically started spinning as per load. I guess my problem is solved then...